# WinApi - override GetMessage loop in WH_GETMESSAGE hook

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, user32

I have implemented standard Win32 MDI window with following message loop:

```
 MSG msg;
 while (NativeMethods.GetMessage(out msg, this.handle, 0, 0) > 0)
 {
       if (!NativeMethods.TranslateMDISysAccel(this.mdiClientHandle, ref msg))
            {
                NativeMethods.TranslateMessage(ref msg);
                NativeMethods.DispatchMessage(ref msg);
            }
        }
  }
```

I am trying to override this message loop by using WH_GETMESSAGE hook. The hook is set correctly and works.

```
  private static IntPtr MyGetMessageHook(int code, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
    {
        if (code == 0)
        {
            MSG msg = (MSG)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lparam, typeof(MSG));

            Debug.WriteLine(msg.message);

            // Execute GetMessage loop logic.
            if (!NativeMethods.TranslateMDISysAccel(MyMdiWindow.MdiClientHandle, ref msg))
            {
                NativeMethods.TranslateMessage(ref msg);
                NativeMethods.DispatchMessage(ref msg);
            }

            // Set msg fields to 0.
            msg.message = 0;
            msg.hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            msg.lParam = IntPtr.Zero;
            msg.wParam = IntPtr.Zero;

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(msg, lparam, true);
        }

        return new IntPtr(NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, code, wparam, lparam));
    }
```

The code in hook procedure executes, but I don't know why window doesn't respond. msg.message is being set to 0 after dispatching it. What happens with message after calling DispatchMessage?

Comment: Why are you even doing this? o.O

Comment: It is just a playground. I am preparing for integrating native MDI Window app (created in external native DLL) with WPF application.

Comment: *"window doesn't respond"* - That's a bit terse. Which window are you expecting to respond, to what, and when?

Comment: Does an empty hook work?  That is, does it work if you take out the code immediately under "Execute GetMessage loop logic" and the code immediately under "Set msg fields to 0" but leave everything else intact?

Comment: I also note that you're calling DispatchMessage etc. without first allowing any other hooks to process the original message.  You might need to call `CallNextHookEx` *before* intercepting the message.

Comment: "window doesn't respond" - main window is frozen, I can't move it, resize it, close and so on. I have removed the code from GetMessage loop and removed msg.message = 0 from hook procedure. It works now. I don't understand what happens in CallNextHookEx method that setting it to 0 after DispatchMessage cause freezing the window.